# Button Image Repeated On cell

Tags: audio, swift3, avaudioplayer

I want to play audio on click on cell. And change button image.They work fine. But when i am scroll my 4 cell button image automatically change.Please help. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
   @IBAction func playSong (_ sender : UIButton , event: UIEvent){


    let buttonPosition:CGPoint =  sender.convert(.zero, to: table)
    let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let cell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as? CustumCell
    let a = URL(string : "http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3")


        if((audioPlayers) != nil){
            audioPlayers = nil
        }
        audioPlayers = AVPlayer(url: a!)

        if sender.isSelected == false {
            sender.isSelected = true
             audioPlayers?.play()
            cell?.play.setImage(UIImage(named : "homestop"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            sender.isSelected = false
            audioPlayers?.pause()
           cell?.play.setImage(UIImage(named : "homeplay"), for: .normal)
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CustumCell"
        var cell: CustumCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CustumCell
        if cell == nil {
            var nib : Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustumCell",owner: self,options: nil)!
            cell = nib[4] as? CustumCell
        }
        cell.reportView.isHidden = true
        cell.play.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.play.addTarget(self, action:#selector(playSong(_:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.homereport.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.homereport.addTarget(self, action:#selector(showReportView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically whenever you scroll down/top/left/right and your marked cell going to out of bounds then whenever you back with scroll the `cellForRowAt` going to be called once more.

I sugest you to create dictionary with `[UITableViewCell : Bool]` and inside :

```
if sender.isSelected == false {
            sender.isSelected = true
             audioPlayers?.play()
            dic[cell] = true
            cell?.play.setImage(UIImage(named : "homestop"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            sender.isSelected = false
            audioPlayers?.pause()
           dic[cell] = false
           cell?.play.setImage(UIImage(named : "homeplay"), for: .normal)
        }
```

Later on inside :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CustumCell"
        var cell: CustumCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CustumCell
        if cell == nil {
            var nib : Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustumCell",owner: self,options: nil)!
            cell = nib[4] as? CustumCell
        }
        cell.reportView.isHidden = true
        cell.play.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.play.addTarget(self, action:#selector(playSong(_:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.homereport.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.homereport.addTarget(self, action:#selector(showReportView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        if dic[cell] {
        // Set the image of the button or what ever you like to :)  
        }
        return cell
    }
```